# Get two words from URL with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get two words from an URL. So for example I have the following URL:

http://mydomain.com/alrajhi/invoice/108678645541

I need to get with PHP only "alrajhi"and the number "108678645541" nothing else.

Can i know how to echo this with "preg_match" function?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with a regular expression?

```
$path = parse_url('http://mydomain.com/alrajhi/invoice/108678645541', PHP_URL_PATH);
list(, $name, , $number) = explode('/', $path);
```

Demo - http://ideone.com/8850lw

Answer (score 0):

Prefer use explode for performance here:

```
<?php
$parts = explode ( '/', "http://mydomain.com/alrajhi/invoice/108678645541e");
$word1 = part[3];
$word2 = part[5];
```

If you want to stick with a regex:
http://regex101.com/r/iY7lJ8

Answer (score 0):

Here is the RegEx:

```
^\/?(\w*)/invoice/(\d*)\/?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VB6c4GiBIPGLKG-j)

PHP Code:

Use documentation: http://www.php.net/preg_match